# sp_executesql wrong syntax

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I get this error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near '='.

When I execute this

```
 exec sp_executesql N' UPADTE SYS_Configuracion
                       SET Valor = @Valor
                       WHERE Codigo = @Codigo',
                    N'@Codigo nvarchar(15),@Valor nvarchar(1)',
                    @Codigo=N'CAP_CERTIF_ADIC',@Valor=N'0'
```

Comment: You have misspelled UPDATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have misspelled UPDATE, you have UPADTE